# Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.fcm error 501)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating my Xamarin.iOS app with Firebase push notifications but getting this **error Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.fcm error 501)** I have added Development certificate APNS key and fulfilled other requirements but unable to get FCM token. Can anybody please help? Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using App.Pages;
using SupportWidgetXF.iOS;
using UserNotifications;
using Firebase.CloudMessaging;
using Firebase.InstanceID;


namespace App.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
           // Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            // get permission for notification

            //  SupportWidgetXFSetup.Initialize(this);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
                Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
                var toke = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;
                var tokenx = Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken;
                string token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;

                //  var token = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) => {
                var newToken = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
                // if you want to send notification per user, use this token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

                connectFCM();
            });            

            string fcm = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken;
        //    Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;

           // PushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");
            // Dependency.DataManager.FCMToken = fcmToken;
        }
        [Export("messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:")]
        public void DidRefreshRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( $" FCM Token: { fcmToken } ");
        }
        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();
        }

        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            connectFCM();
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
#if DEBUG
            //InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Sandbox);
#endif
#if RELEASE
            Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.SetApnsToken(deviceToken, Firebase.InstanceID.ApnsTokenType.Prod);
#endif
        }

        // iOS 9 <=, fire when recieve notification foreground
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

            // Generate custom event
            NSString[] keys = { new NSString("Event_type") };
            NSObject[] values = { new NSString("Recieve_Notification") };
            var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);

            // Send custom event
            //Firebase.Analytics.Analytics.LogEvent("CustomEvent", parameters);

            if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userInfo);
                var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
                var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
                var body = alert_d["body"] as NSString;
                var title = alert_d["title"] as NSString;
                debugAlert(title, body);
            }
        }

        // iOS 10, fire when recieve notification foreground
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            var title = notification.Request.Content.Title;
            var body = notification.Request.Content.Body;
            debugAlert(title, body);
        }

        private void connectFCM()
        {
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
           // Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect((error) =>
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    Messaging.SharedInstance.Subscribe("/topics/all");
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error != null ? "error occured" : "connect success");
            });
        }

        private void debugAlert(string title, string message)
        {
            var alert = new UIAlertView(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", null, "Cancel", "OK");
            alert.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there somebody to help? i am still stucked :(

Comment: Hi, you can have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/samples/Firebase/CloudMessaging/CloudMessagingSample/AppDelegate.cs) from xamarin iOS .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks for your kind suggestion tried with your provided code but same. no method is being called even DidReceiveRegistrationToken. I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Okey , before using firebase-cloud-messaging , I will check whether the **App ID** contains the service of `Push Notifications` . You can also check that first .

Comment: Where to check? & how to?

Comment: Oh , forget to share this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios#creating-and-using-certificates

Comment: Thanks for sharing but i've already gone through this doc & already done all the required things.

Comment: I've already entered authentication key & APNs certificate of Development.

Comment: Okey , it's strange . When you first lauch app , does the permission alert of notification pop up ?

Comment: Dear thanks for your precious time the issue has been resolved. The issue was i was testing on simulator but when i tested on physical device. it works :)

Comment: Okey , that's right . Remote notification can not be tested in Simulator device , you should test it in physical device .

Comment: Yeah but one more thing that may be helped i switched my provisioning profile to another than set it back may be that solved the issue now it's also working on simulator too. :)

Comment: Interseting , you can check the `fcmToken` whether get when test in simulator .

Comment: Yes i've got the token & remote message as well now :)

Comment: Awesome ! That means switching provisioning profile can make all them work .

Comment: Yes it did the trick for me. when i connect physical device it was showing some error of provisioning profiles then i reset profiles then installed & worked like a charm :)

Comment: Dear @JuniorJiang-MSFT i am having a new issue could you please solve it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563658/firebase-push-notification-receiving-only-when-app-is-in-foreground-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was i was testing on simulator but when i tested on physical device. it works. But one more thing that may be helped i switched my provisioning profile to another than set it back may be that solved the issue now it's also working on simulator too.